# Initialising actions for buttons that are not on the screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity where either buttonA or buttonB may be present.

In landscape buttonA is present
In portrait buttonB is present

My code in the activity onCreate is below

```
Button nextToBtnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA);
if (nextToBtnA != null ){
     nextToBtnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do button A stuff
        }});
}
Button nextToBtnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnB);
if (nextToBtnB != null ){
      nextToBtnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //do button B stuff
        }});
}
```

My problem is that if I start the activity in landscape I an only execute buttonA. If I change to portrait then buttonB's event listener hasnt been executed so clicking on it does nothing.

How can I get it to re-register the event listeners on orientation change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get it to re-register the event listeners on orientation change.

Remove the `android:configChanges` attribute in this activity's `<activity>` element in the manifest, so your activity is destroyed and recreated. In the new instance of your activity, the `onCreate()` logic will run again, and you will set up your UI properly.

Comment: thanks for the V quick reply! Will destroying the activity not have performance implications? If I want to store anything during the orientation change will I not lose it by destroying and recreating?

Comment: @RNJ: "Will destroying the activity not have performance implications?" -- the vast majority of activities in the vast majority of applications are destroyed and recreated on a configuration change. "If I want to store anything during the orientation change will I not lose it by destroying and recreating?" -- not if you write your activity properly. [Handle the configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) using `onSavedInstanceState()`, a retained fragment, etc.